# Is it possible to use PHP script for processing a non-PHP file by calling the file URL directly?

Tags: php, webserver

I need to make a PHP script that will take a filename as an argument, open that file and process it (read and process non-PHP pseudo instructions) and return the result to visitor's browser.

Example:

1. Web site visitor types http://domain.ext/somefilename.myext and web server opens specific PHP script (e.g. MyMainScript.php) passing full path to somefilename.myext as an argument.
2. MyMainScript.php opens the file somefilename.myext, reads whatever is in it, processes it and sends output back to visitor's browser

So my question is how to configure web server (IIS or Apache) to map files with file extension "myext" (*.myext) to execute script " MyMainScript.php"

Calling it using some other way, like:

```
/MyMainScript.php/somefilename.myext
```

or

```
/MyMainScript.php?file=somefilename.myext
```

is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file at the root of your website. If you are running Apache2 @ Ubuntu/Debian, use this directive:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .myext
```

If your are running PHP as CGI, you should write this instead:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .myext
```

This will treat specific extensions as PHP files and execute them as PHP.

Another solution might be a RewriteRule, so you can specify which file needs to be executed, for Apache your .htaccess file should look like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^somefilename.myext$ ./MyMainScript.php?file=somefilename.myext

# or just for any file ending with .myext
RewriteRule ^(.*).myext$ ./MyMainScript.php?file=$1.myext
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this second solution RewriteRule might be what I need, but I have to ask few more questions:

1. Where this .htaccess file should be located (wwwroot I guess)
2. If I configue my files like this, will MyMainScript.php get all the parameters (both get and post) that were sent to somefilename.myext

Thanks

Comment: 1. yes just in the root of your public_html folder, where your index file is located. 2. yes this works for both get and post

Comment: Thanks!!!
Based on your answer I made this and it works perfectly

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+).myext$ /MyMainScript.php?file=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>`

The only thing that troubles me now is if there are any specific security risks/holes in this code?

Comment: In that case, if you can accept my answer that would be great :) About your security issue: just make sure the filename (filename.myext) cannot contain any malicious code. So perhaps `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z+).myext$ /MyMainScript.php?file=$1` is better. In this case only letters from a till z are allowed (upper- and lowercase)